# Using MPI to matrix multiply

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to run an MPI matrix multiply example except I modified it to read files and of course things blow up.

Specifically I get this error:

```
Entering first MPI_Recv in p0 and recieving data from slave processor 1
Fatal error in MPI_Recv: Invalid count, error stack:
MPI_Recv(186): MPI_Recv(buf=0xbfd30930, count=-1807265191, MPI_FLOAT, src=0, tag=1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status=0x804b080) failed
MPI_Recv(104): Negative count, value is -1807265191
```

Here is the modified code:

```
 MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);  
 MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);  
 MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);  
 slaves = p-1;  //slaves=numworkers
 /*---------------------------- master ----------------------------*/  
 if(id == 0) 
   {  
  /* check the number of arguments */

    if(argc!=4)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of aguements!\n./program matrix_file1 matrix_file2 result_matrix_file\n");
        return -1;
    }

         /* read matrix A */
    printf("read matrix A from %s\n", argv[1]);
    read_matrix( argv[1],&a, &sa, &i, &j);

    if(i != j) 
    { 
        printf("ERROR: matrix A not square\n"); 
        return -1;
    }

        

    n = i;



  /* read matrix B */
     printf("read matrix B from %s\n", argv[2]);
     read_matrix(argv[2],&b, &sb, &i, &j);

     

    if(i != j) 
    {     
          printf("ERROR: matrix B not square\n"); 
          return -1; 
    }   

    if(n != i) 
    {   printf("ERROR: matrix A and B incompatible\n"); 
        return -1; 
    }



    if((n%p)!=0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: %d processor(s) cannot divide matrices %d x %d! \n", p,n,n); 
        return -1;
    }
    
    
 
        rows = n/slaves;
        offset=0;
        remainPart=n%slaves;


    for(dest=1;dest<=slaves;dest++)
    {
        

        if(remainPart>0)
        {
            originalRows=rows;
            ++rows;
            remainPart--;
             printf("Sending %d rows to task %d offset=%d\n",rows,dest,offset);
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
            MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
            MPI_Send(&a[offset][0], rows*n, MPI_FLOAT,dest,1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
            MPI_Send(&b, n*n, MPI_FLOAT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
            offset = offset + rows;   
            rows = originalRows;  

        }
        else
        {
             printf("Sending %d rows to task %d offset=%d\n",rows,dest,offset);
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
            MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
            MPI_Send(&a[offset][0], rows*n, MPI_FLOAT,dest,1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
            MPI_Send(&b, n*n, MPI_FLOAT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
            offset = offset + rows; 
        }
    }
    /* initialize matrix C */

    sc = (float*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(float));
    memset(sc, 0, n*n*sizeof(float));
    c = (float**)malloc(n*sizeof(float*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) c[i] = &sc[i*n];

    /* wait for results from all worker tasks */  
   for (k=1; k<=slaves; k++)      
   {              
    source = k;  
    printf("Entering first MPI_Recv in p0 and recieving data from slave processor %d\n", source);
    MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
    printf("Entering second MPI_Recv in p0\n"); 
    MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("Entering third MPI_Recv in p0\n");  
    MPI_Recv(&c[offset][0], rows*n, MPI_FLOAT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
   }     
    

   write_matrix(argv[3], sc, i, j);

    free(sc);
    free(c);
  }   



if(id>0)
{
      source = 0; 
        //printf("Entered first MPI_Recv for process %d\n", id); 
       MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
        //printf("Entered second MPI_Recv for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
        //printf("Entered third MPI_Recv for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Recv(&a, rows*n, MPI_FLOAT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        //printf("Entered fourth MPI_Recv for process %d\n", id);  
       MPI_Recv(&b, n*n, MPI_FLOAT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
       /* Matrix multiplication */  
       for (k=0; k<n; k++)  
        for (l=0; l<rows; l++) {   
         for (m=0; m<n; m++)  
          c[l][k] = c[l][k] + a[l][m] * b[m][k];  
        }  


        //printf("Entered first MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        //printf("Entered second MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        //printf("Entered third MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Send(&c, rows*n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  

        
}






MPI_Finalize();}
```

Before hand I was incorrectly going through all the processes instead of just the workers so I had fixed that but I have no clue where the random negative number shows up from. Especially since what follows after the the print statement

```
printf("Entering first MPI_Recv in p0 and recieving data from slave processor %d\n", source);
    MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
    printf("Entering second MPI_Recv in p0\n"); 
    MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("Entering third MPI_Recv in p0\n");  
    MPI_Recv(&c[offset][0], rows*n, MPI_FLOAT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Is nothing but ones and the original dimension n multiplied by the average of the rows given to the slaves.

Update: Ok so part of the problem seems to be while my arrays have had space allocated in the master it's not so for slave processes.

Upon realizing this I've added buffers for the matrices transferred their data before checking if processors were the workers. Though apparently the print statements won't show up so obviously it is not working exactly as planned.

```
float buffA[n][n];
float buffB[n][n];
float buffC[n][n];

for(l=0;l<n;l++)
    for(m=0;m<n;m++)
    {
        buffA[l][m]=a[l][m];
        buffB[l][m]=b[l][m];

                        //buffA[l][m]=sa[(i*n) + j];
                        //buffB[l][m]=sb[(i*n) + j];
        printf("buffA[%d][%d] =%f\n",l,m, buffA[l][m]);
        printf("buffB[%d][%d] =%f\n",l,m,buffB[l][m]);
    }

if(id>0)
{
        /*read_matrix( argv[1],&a, &sa, &i, &j);
        read_matrix(argv[2],&b, &sb, &i, &j);*/



        source = 0; 
        printf("Entered first MPI_Recv for process %d\n", id); 
       MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
        printf ("offset =%d\n", offset);
       MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
        printf ("row =%d\n", rows);
       MPI_Recv(&buffA[offset][0], rows*n, MPI_FLOAT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("buffA[offset][0] =%f\n", buffA[offset][0]); //they're not getting the matrices 
       MPI_Recv(&buffB, n*n, MPI_FLOAT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
        //printf ("b=\n");

       /* Matrix multiplication */  
       for (k=0; k<n; k++)  
        for (l=0; l<rows; l++) {   
            //c[l][k]=0.0;
         for (m=0; m<n; m++)  
          buffC[l][k] = buffC[l][k] + buffA[l][m] * buffB[m][k];  
            //printf("c[%d][%d]= %f\n", l,k, c[l][k]);
        }  


        //printf("Entered first MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        //printf("Entered second MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        //printf("Entered third MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Send(&buffC, rows*n, MPI_FLOAT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  

        printf("Exit via MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
}
```

The error number number has also changed though I'm not sure if this signifies anything.

```
Fatal error in MPI_Recv: Invalid count, error stack:
MPI_Recv(186): MPI_Recv(buf=0xbf8e642c, count=-8, MPI_FLOAT, src=0, tag=1,MPI_COMM_WORLD, status=0x804c088) failed
MPI_Recv(104): Negative count, value is -8
```

Okay so now I figured out that that the dimension n was not being transfered, and that was causing the initial random negative number. So I added a send and recv for n. And now it seems the final question is how to transfer dynamically allocated arrays for MPI. Still working on that.

**Update**

It works, current worker code is like so, though the multiplication is all over the place but baby steps I suppose. XP

```
if(id>0)
{

        


        source = 0; 
        printf("Entered first MPI_Recv for process %d\n", id); 
       MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
        printf ("offset =%d\n", offset);
       MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
         MPI_Recv(&n, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
        printf ("row =%d\nn=%d\n", rows,n);

        float buffA[rows][n];
        float buffB[n][n];
        float buffC[rows][n];

        
       MPI_Recv(&buffA[offset][0], rows*n, MPI_FLOAT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("buffA[offset][0] =%f\n", buffA[offset][0]); //they're not getting the matrices 
       MPI_Recv(&buffB, n*n, MPI_FLOAT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
        //printf ("b=\n");

       /* Matrix multiplication */  
       for (k=0; k<n; k++)  
        for (l=0; l<rows; l++) {   
            //c[l][k]=0.0;
         for (m=0; m<n; m++)  
          //buffC[l][k] = buffC[l][k] + buffA[l][m] * buffB[m][k];  
            //printf("c[%d][%d]= %f\n", l,k, c[l][k]);
            buffC[l][k] = buffC[l][k] + buffA[l][m] * buffB[m][k];  

        }  


        //printf("Entered first MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        //printf("Entered second MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        //printf("Entered third MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
       MPI_Send(&buffC, rows*n, MPI_FLOAT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  

        printf("Exit via MPI_send for process %d\n", id);
}
```

Result

```
0.00 -0.00 -0.00 -0.00 -0.00 -0.00 0.00 0.00 
0.00 -0.00 -0.00 -0.00 -1.26 -1.26 -0.00 -1.26 
-0.00 -1.26 -0.00 0.00 -0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 
-0.00 0.00 -0.00 -0.00 0.00 -0.00 -0.00 0.00 
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 -0.00 -1.26 -0.00 0.00 
-0.00 -0.00 0.00 35833769696167556769392596671120015360.00 0.00 0.00 -0.00 0.00 
-0.00 -0.00 0.00 -0.00 -0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 
0.00 -nan -0.00 -0.00 -0.00 -0.00 -0.00 -0.00
```

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger through it? The code isn't that long. You could break on calls to MPI_Recv and figure out what's going on relatively easily I think.

Comment: So far I've used nothing but print statements. Any recommendations? Normal gdb seems a bit complicated.

Comment: Alright worth a shot.

Comment: For MPI debugging, I'm also a fan of running multiple instances of gdb. I usually do something like `mpirun -np N xterm -e gdb ./mpiprog`, then I can debug all of the threads in parallel to watch sends and receives happening and such. In that example, `N` should be small so you don't have tons of windows to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

(moved from a comment so this question can be answered)

Print statements are wildly unreliable in a distributed environment. There's no guarantee that they arrive in order in relation to one another. GDB really isn't that bad. You don't need to attach to all of the processes, just pick one. You can check out my answer over here (stackoverflow.com/questions/17347778/…) to see how to do it.

Comment: But this isn't an answer to the question.  It would be better all round if OP posted an answer to her own question rather than editing an answer into the question itself.  There is no need for the question to have an answer and a comment masquerading as an answer is still a comment.

Comment: Fair enough. Really, this question should probably be closed as what used to be called "too localized" since that's what debugging questions are. However, I looked at meta for some advice here and found (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125384/debug-this-code-for-me-questions) that the accepted response here is to tell people how to debug as an answer. If this gets closed though, I wouldn't object. I just don't know what the OP will say that would really be an "answer" to this "question".